# Извлечь и переместить элемент с помощью функции toArray()

Tags: jquery

Как извлечь параграф используя метод toArray()?

Код почти готов, необходимо добавить функцию для извлечения (именно с toArray()) и переместить в конец после div.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> 5. 3 Перемещение </title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload=function(){
        $("#get").click(function(){
            alert($("div").get(1).tagName)
            alert($("div").get(1).className)
            alert($("div").get())
        })
        $("#start").click(function(){
            $("div").each(function(index,elementDOM){
                $(elementDOM).css("backgroundColor", "#95AFC1").text("DIV"+index);
            });
            $("#move").click(function(){
                $("p").toArray().insertBefore ($("div:last"))
            })
        });
    }
</script>
<style>
.red 
{
    padding:25px; margin:10px; background-color:red;float:left;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <p class="red"></p>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <input type="button" id='start' value="Пуск!">
    <input type="button" id='get' value="Метод get()">
    <input type="button" id='move' value="Извлечь и переместить p">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень даже легко, дело в том, что `toArray()` преобразует jquery объект в plain massiv, обычный -javascript-массив элементов, у которого нет методов и свойств jquery, оборачиваем опять в доллар и работаем дальше.

`$("#move").click()` помещать внутрь другого `click()` в вашем примере не правильно.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title> 5. 3 Перемещение </title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function() {
   $("#get").click(function() {
    alert($("div").get(1).tagName)
    alert($("div").get(1).className)
    alert($("div").get())
   });

   $("#start").click(function() {
    $("div").each(function(index, elementDOM) {
     $(elementDOM).css("backgroundColor", "#95AFC1").text("DIV" + index);
    });
   });

   $("#move").click(function() {
    var p = $("p").toArray();
    console.log(p);
    $(p).insertAfter($("div:last"));
   });


  }
  </script>
  <style>
  .red
  {
  padding:25px; margin:10px; background-color:red;float:left;
  }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="red"></div>
  <p class="red"></p>
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="red"></div>
  <input type="button" id='start' value="Пуск!">
  <input type="button" id='get' value="Метод get()">
  <input type="button" id='move' value="Извлечь и переместить p">
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо, всё ясно!